# how to auto switch form after my progress bar reach 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do is after the progress bar reach `100%` it will auto direct to `Profile form` without clicking the link iv made.

My problem is i dont know how to make it redirect to profile form without clicking the link after progress reach 100%. And progress bar reset again if the home link is press again.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/71/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect to Profile form you could `trigger` a `click` on the proper selector like :

```
$(".show-page[data-page=Profile]").trigger("click");
```

To reset the home page, I would advise you to move your `setInterval()` within a external function that you can call when the `Home` link is clicked

```
if (pageToShow == "Home") {
    // reset progress var
    value = 0;
    $('.bar').width(0);
    $('.progress').addClass('active');
    progressBar();
} else {
    clearInterval(progress);
};
```

The full code

```
// vars 
var value = 0, progress;

//progress bar script
function progressBar() {
    progress = setInterval(function () {
        var $bar = $('.bar');
        if (value >= 100) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
            // go to profile after progress bar reaches 100%
            $(".show-page[data-page=Profile]").trigger("click");
        } else {
            value += 10;
            $bar.width(value * 4);
        }
        $bar.text(value + "%");
    }, 800);
};
//for my show and hide form script
$(document).ready(function () {
    progressBar();
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined" && sessionStorage.getItem('pageToShow')) {
        var pageToShow = sessionStorage.getItem('pageToShow');
        $('.page').addClass('hide');
        $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
    };
    $('.show-page').click(function () {
        var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');
        if (pageToShow == "Home") {
            // reset progress var
            value = 0;
            $('.bar').width(0);
            $('.progress').addClass('active');
            progressBar();
        } else {
            clearInterval(progress);
        };
        $('.page').addClass('hide');
        $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            sessionStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
        };
    });
    $('.modal-btn').click(function () {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

See your forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/)**

Comment: y does Profile form show first in jsfiddle? I want the Home with progress bar show first then redirect to Profile form.

Comment: it's because you are using `sessionStorage`, this is why you see profile first; you may need to reset that value, let me fork the fiddle